# Using an array of any Object as a parameter in java then using methods declared in both objects

Tags: java, methods, types, parameters, parameter-passing

I have a method header as such

```
public static void test (Object[] queue) {
     queue.dequeue();
}
```

Where Object will either be ArrayListQueue or LinkedListQueue and will store Strings in either case. In either case working written methods for dequeue have been written.

I effectively would like the method to work like this

```
public static void test ( (ArrayListQueue or LinkedListQueue) [] queue) {
     queue.dequeue();
}
```

Does anyone have any idea? Thank you.

Edit : The Object can not implement an interface.

Comment: You should learn about [generics](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-generics/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

This would typically be done with a common superclass (or interface):

```
abstract class Type0 {
    abstract void deque();
}

class Type1 extends Type0 {
    @Override
    void deque() { thing1(); }
}
class Type2 extends Type0 {
    @Override
    void deque() { thing2(); }
}

public static void test(Type0[] queue) {
    for(Type0 t : queue) t.deque();
}
```

Very occasionally casting is appropriate:

```
public static void test(Object[] queue) {
    for(Object o : queue) {
        if(o instanceof Type1) {
            Type1 t1 = (Type1)o;
            t1.deque1();
        } else if(o instanceof Type2) {
            Type2 t2 = (Type2)o;
            t2.deque2();
        }
    }
}
```

See also [inheritance tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html).

Comment: *"Ex: ArrayQueue[] queue or LinkedListQueue[] queue"* This is what my answer addressed. `ArrayQueue[]` is an array whose elements are `ArrayQueue` and `LinkedListQueue[]` is an array whose elements are `LinkedListQueue`. And my answer says typically `ArrayQueue` and `LinkedListQueue` would have a common superclass. If you still think this does not address what you are asking then you should edit the question to clarify what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Just define two methods with different type of argument and one more private method for actual implementation. Something like this:

```
public static void test(ArrayListQueue[] queue) {
    testImpl(queue);
}

public static void test(LinkedListQueue[] queue) {
    testImpl(queue);
}

private static void testImpl(Object[] queue) {
    for (Object obj : queue) {
        if (obj instanceof Queue1) {
            ((Queue1) obj).dequeue();
        } else if (obj instanceof Queue2) {
            ((Queue2) obj).dequeue();
        } else {
            // Another queue
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either overloading:

```
public static void test (ArrayListQueue[] queue) {
    queue.dequeue();
}

public static void test (LinkedListQueue[] queue) {
    queue.dequeue();
}
```

Or an abstract type (only possible if both classes implement/extend a common type:

```
public static void test (SomeCommonQueue[] queue) {
    queue.dequeue();
}
```

The second option is preferable: See [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)